# Accessing kubernetics service from outside pod but within the cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Am running several services on same port within my kubernetes cluster; so its like ser1, ser2, ser3 all using same port 8080.  I can access these services from inside a pod as `<serv-name>:8080` but can I also access them in same way from one of the host nodes i.e. outside a container but from one of the cluster nodes ?

I tried looking around but did not find any relevant discussion on this. Pls if someone may suggest.

my sample config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc1
  namespace: sample
  labels:
    app: svc1
spec:
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
  - name: psvc1
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 9090
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Have you tried exposing the service with the type clusterIP? This should give you a virtual cluster-wide IP that you can call with the specified port.

Comment: Thanks @DriesDeRydt. Yes, I can access through cluster-IP. But same clusterIP may not always be available when a service is launched or restarted. Is there a way to tell Kubernetes to reserve such virtual IPs or more appropriately a range of virtual IPs. I need to configure these clusterIPs in my load-balancer.

Comment: yes, you can specify the IP: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#choosing-your-own-ip-address

Comment: @MarcSluiter Agreed that clusterIp works but how do I control that the clusterIp I chose is not already allocated at first time of my container's launch or when it restarts. Can you re-direct me to any link where I can see details on whats the value of service-cluster-ip-range and how I can tell k8es to NOT to use the some custerIP before my container has launched.

Comment: `service-cluster-ip-range` is an option of kube-apiserver, so just check what's configured there. No idea how k8s handles potential conflicts, sorry

Comment: but maybe I have a better idea: did you configure DNS in your k8s cluster? Then just use the service name, and you don't have to care about IPs anymore. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Answer (score 1):

as Dries said, using cluster IP we can access the service from node.

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 --expose=true

kubectl  get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   9d
nginx        ClusterIP   10.103.206.246   <none>        80/TCP    52m


# curl 10.103.206.246:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
```